# Timemachine backups on encrypted volume: What does 'decrypting' message mean?

Tags: time-machine, backup, encryption

I backup files on an encrypted volume with Timemachine (external disk, USB). The backup itself is not additionally encrypted.

I noticed little message infos in the GUI window about "decrypting the backup-volume" sometimes, e.g. when I exclude some files from the backup.

What does that mean? I thought the encryption during file copy process in both directions is handled transparently? Is there any moment where something is not encrypted on the volume?

Comment: Something what is encrypted, and you want to see it has to be decrypted somehow..

Comment: But if I exclude smth. via Time-machine settings, I choose a folder on the source side, not the target. I've seen it also w/out doing anything actively (when clicking on the TM icon) @Robuust